# spread operator in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In the below code,

```
function myFunction(x, y, z) { }
var args = [0, 1, 2];
myFunction(...args);
```

Is spread operator(`...`) unpacking the array and providing 3 values 0, 1, 2?

Comment: What is "spread operator"?

Comment: @Teemu - it's new to me too, but it's [part of ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Comment: It is also called the "splat operator".

Comment: In short, `myFunction(...args);` is the same as `myFunction(0,1,2);`.

Comment: Can't you just try it out? -1 for not doing any research.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as per [the page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) that contains the example you posted:

> The spread operator allows an expression to be expanded in places where multiple arguments (for function calls) or multiple elements (for array literals) are expected.

Running the following through an [ES6 transpiler](https://babeljs.io/):

```
function myFunction(x, y, z) {
  console.log(x,y,z);
}
var args = [0, 1, 2];
myFunction(...args);
```

produces:

```
function myFunction(x, y, z) {
  console.log(x, y, z);
}
var args = [0, 1, 2];
myFunction.apply(undefined, args);
```

which logs `0 1 2`, showing it has expanded the `args` array.

Comment: Since you've already gone through all this, it's worth noting that the transpiler only produces this code (`apply`) in this case, and the operator can generate different "ES5 equivalents" in other uses

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's exactly what the spread operator does.

It is the equivalent of replacing the identifier containing the iterable with an comma seperated list of values that are the output of iterating the iterable.

In your case, the iterable is an array, and the equivalent is `0, 1, 2`.

Had the iterable been the output of a generator function it would be the same:

```
function* f1() {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}

var a = [...f1()];
// the above is IDENTICAL to [1, 2, 3]
```

A powerful use of the operator is when values are not "static" like this:

```
function* f2(totalCount) {
  let count= 1;
  while(totalCount-- > 0) {
    yield count++;
  }
}

var b = [...f2(5)];
// b is equal to [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: You shouldn't post a "yes" as an answer.

Comment: Should I post a no? The question is a yes or no type of question, and leaves no room for an extended answer in this case

Comment: @Chrillewoodz - it's your right to donwvote, and I do agree that a "Yes" can be "answered" as a comment, but that just leaves questions unanswered in many cases, and my opinion is that the question is very specific and leaves no room for more than that.

Comment: Nothing personal but I feel James' answer is a better example of a "yes" answer. I'll be happy to upvote if you provide a useful edit.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz - I feel like I'm being pulled in here, but what the heck - you have a follower :-) (Pending edit...)

Answer (score 0):

`...` is known as Spread/Rest operator depending upon how and where it is used.

**What does spread operator do?** The spread operator allows an expression to be expanded in places where multiple elements/variables/arguments are expected.

Before ES6, arguments is an array like object, corresponds to the arguments passed to a function. Here is a quick look at its use:

```
(function(a, b, c){
   console.log(arguments);
})(1, 2, 3);
Output would be [1,2,3].
```

In ES6, the same can be written as:

```
function getSum(x, y, z){
   console.log(x+y+z);
}
```

can call either of two ways:

```
getSum(...[10,20,30]);
```

or

```
var argArr = [10,20,30];
getSume(...argArr);
```

We have put `...` in front of array, so it spread the elements of array into individual values.